# Increment an integer to be used as an index for new MySQL entries. Is there a better way?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a MySQL table of unique usernames and other properties. I read it's faster to look things up by an integer index (instead of a string) so I want each username to have a unique integer.

Currently, I have an extra table in my database which contains a single value: the "free" index. When a new user is created, it takes this values and pairs it with the username, then increments the value in the table.

It seems awkward having this extra table and performing commands on it. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can add INTEGER column with name 'id' to you table and set PRIMARY AUTO INCREMENTAL key on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at `AUTO_INCREMENT` option which can be used like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  email CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Afterwards, you may add new users without mentioning the `id` field:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ("John Dow", "jdow@email.com"), ("Alice Dow", "adow@gmail.com");
```

Nevertheless, when you `SELECT` from `users`, you will see `id` autoincrementing:

```
SELECT * from users;
```

will print out:

```
+----+-----------+----------------+
| id |    name   |     email      |
+----+-----------+----------------+
|  1 | John Dow  | jdow@email.com |
|  2 | Alice Dow | adow@gmail.com |
+----+-----------+----------------+
```

However, most likely you won't see any significant performance improvement with numeric ids.
Non-username ids are covenient if users are allowed to change their usernames. Otherwise, I would stick to username as an id and primary index.

Comment: You need to put `NULL` in the place of the `id` column in the `VALUES`.

Comment: Or list the columns to insert and leave out the `id` column when you do that.

Comment: Good comment. Thank you for being so attentive and quick.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store the integer index in the same table? So it'd be like another column which is auto-increasing and you could use that for lookup.

Comment: I guess that would work if it is the first entry.

Example:

0 Null

To add a user, find Null (the free index), take the 0 for the new user and increment it for Null:

1 Null
0 abcde

Sounds like it will work.